# iseries datasource lock timeout

Tags: websphere, ibm-midrange

we're having an issue with lock timeouts connecting from a was 6 server to an iseries v6r1 db.

We have the default table and record lock wait times on the relevant tables, however these seem to be overridden by the transaction (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzakj/rzakjrecords.htm) suggests this is what's happening.

We're using the XA toolbox driver (com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCXADataSource); does anyone know where we can configure the default lock wait time on this driver? I can't find any documentation anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems finding answers trying posting your message to [WEB400](http://murl.com/web400) at [midrange.com](http://midrange.com). There are several people who use WebSphere App Server on there.